# Count words without checking that a word is "in" dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I understand that there are modules out there that can do this kind of behavior, but I'm interested in how to approach the following "issue".

Whenever I used to want to count occurrences I found it a bit silly I had to first check for whether or not a key is "in" the dictionary (#1). I believe at the time I even used a try...exception because I didn't know how to do it properly.

```
# 1
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
dicty = {}
for w in words:
    if w in dicty:
        dicty[w] += 1
    else:
        dicty[w] = 1
```

At this moment, I'm interested in the question what has to be done to make a class "SpecialDictionary" behave such that if a word is not in a dictionary, it automatically gets a default 0 value (#2). Which concepts are needed for this question?

Note: I understand that this "in" check could be done in the class' definition, but there must be something more pythonic/elegant?

```
# 2
special_dict = SpecialDictionary()        
for w in words:
    special_dict[w] += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `dict` and override its `__missing__` method to return 0:

```
class SpecialDictionary(dict):
    def __missing__(self, k):
        return 0

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
special_dict = SpecialDictionary()        
for w in words:
    special_dict[w] += 1
print special_dict
#{'c': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for x in words:
...     my_dict[x] = my_dict.get(x,0) + 1
... 
>>> my_dict
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

`dict.get` returns the value of the key if present, else a default
Syntax: `dict.get(key,[default])`

you can also use try and except, if key is not found in dictionary it raises `keyError`:

```
>>> for x in words:
...     try:
...         my_dict[x] += 1
...     except KeyError:
...         my_dict[x] = 1
... 
>>> my_dict
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

using `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>> my_count = Counter(words)
>>> my_count
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Comment: First sentence in the question, I'm aware of Counter.

Comment: @PascalvKooten now check it :)

Comment: Doesn't seem the most performance effective? Still the Counter example is quite invalid. +1 for the creative solution, but the best answer was already given :)

Comment: I find the use of `get()` preferable for this task. If you make the dictionary behave strangely (by subclassing) just for purposes of this loop, you have to remember that it's going to do the same everywhere else you use it.

Comment: Interesting point. Though consider asking the question "how many times does the word 'd' occur in the dictionary (even when it did not get added immediately), you could do `my_dict['d']` and you'd get 0. In this "counting words" type of dictionary application it seems rather sweet 'default' behavior :)

Comment: Also, I even mentioned using the try...except way, that was my first solution year(s) ago haha!

Comment: @PascalvKooten great, i let it be in answer so, other can find useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict`.  Or is this one of the “modules out there” that you wish to avoid?

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
d['a'] += 1
print(d['a'])
print(d['b'])
```

It will print:

```
1
0
```

Comment: Yep, I guess it's an ambiguous question. I'm mostly just interested in ways to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The 'SpecialDictionary' that implements that kind of behavior is the `collections.defaultdict`. It takes a function as first parameter as an default-value-factory. When ever a lookup is performed it checks if the key is already in the dictionary and if thats not the case it uses that factory-function to create  a value which is then added to the dictionary (and returned by the lookup). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) on how it is implemented.

`Counter` is a special variant of the `defaultdict` that uses int as factory-function (and provides some additional methods )